# How to handle side-nav with multiple items?

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation

I have built a `dashboard` where the user can handle totals for all it's *shops*, in a `side-navbar` over the `items` like '*settings*', '*exit*' and **refs** to other pages there are **all shops listed** as tree view, you can open a shop and select the cash-point of which show the data or just deselect a whole shop if you won't see it's data, i think the user must be able to keep an eye on the shops he selected choose to see the data so i decided to place them inside the side-navbar..

There were no issues and it's looked good till i set the dashboard for a client with a lot of shops... and it's horrible... as the **shops are listed before the refs** to other pages the user just can't see them and have to **scroll the navbar**...

So i was wondering on how can i manage the way to let the user keep an eye on shops but till not make that nav-bar look so horrible and confusional..

Should i just put the refs to other pages before listed shops?

Anyway here is how the nav-bar looks like

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the number of refs fixed/limited? any reason why stacking the refs above the shops would not work?

Comment: Also, not really related, but if you are designing for a lot of shops like in your images, I would reduce the height of the elements for shops and POS to give a more compact view. There is enough free space to be able to do that without compromising too much readability

Comment: @bracco23 actually there will be more refs as the site is still under development, the shops are generated dynamically, actually i had a doubt for refs above shops cause idk it look's a bit strange to me..

Comment: From what I see, refs do not have any hidden menu and such, so placing them above is just like displacing the shops lower. I think you could try a few different solutions (shops above, shops below, two level sidenav, etc) and see what your boss thinks about them. A pair of fresh new eyes is always useful.

Comment: You could also put the refs as tabs instead of as sidenav entries.

Comment: @bracco23 actually i changed it as you suggested by moving refs above and by resizing the shops items, now it look's more fancy i think https://imgur.com/pMulzvZ

Comment: "where the user can handle totals for all it's shops" what does "handling" totals involve? Is it just viewing the totals? Seems like your dashboard itself could provide a means to drill-down to granular (per-shop, per-register) level if the User wants to go that far, instead of providing a cumbersome list in the Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have too many items to display, there are different strategies you can take depending on implementation feasibility:

- change the IA so a different structure for the data can be displayed more clearly
- provide a search/filter to reduce the amount of visible items at any given time
- break up the group into logical subgroups (even if it is just all vs. recent)

But you will need to understand the impact this will have on other aspects of the user interface and userflows.